# Quick question about negative variance

Tags: probability

I've been given $E(X)=2$, $E(X^2)=6$, $E(Y)=4$ and $E(Y^2)=20$ and I have been asked to calculate $Var(2X-4Y)$ which seems straightforward since it is just $Var(2X)-Var(4Y)$ $= 4Var(X)-16Var(Y)$. However, from the values given, this gives me a negative variance which I didn't think was possible?

EDIT: Can't seem to add comments for some reason. Silly error though since $Var(2X-4Y)$ should be $Var(2X)+Var(4Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$ - Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Are you sure $\mathrm{Var}(2X-4Y)=\mathrm{Var}(2X)-\mathrm{Var}(4Y)$ ?

Comment: $\mathrm{Var}(2X-4Y)=\mathrm{Var}(2X)+\mathrm{Var}(4Y)$ if $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ (which is true if you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full answer to your question :

What is always true is :

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Var}(2X-4Y) & = & \mathrm{Var}(2X) + \mathrm{Var}(4Y) - 2 \, \mathrm{Cov}(2X,4Y) \\
 & = & 4 \, \mathrm{Var}(X) + 16 \, \mathrm{Var}(Y) - 16 \, \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, then, they are uncorrelated. It means that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$. (Note that the converse is not true). We are missing $\mathrm{E}(XY)$ to compute $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ so let's assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

From the information you gave, we get : $\mathrm{Var}(X) = 6-4 = 2$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y) = 20-16 = 4$. So,

> $$ \mathrm{Var}(2X-4Y) = 4 \times 2 + 16 \times 4 = 72 $$